# PHP get XML from URL with credentials

Tags: php, xml

I have a URL that prompts for a username/password to get its data.  The data is in XML format.  At first I tried to retrieve the data like this:

```
$url = "http://username:password@[ip-address]:8086/connectioncounts?flat";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
print_r($xml);
```

After searching for an answer I've come up with this code:

```
$url = "http://[ip-address]:8086/connectioncounts?flat"; 
$ch = curl_init();     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);  
echo $result;
```

I'm not getting any data returned on either of these attempts. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Also use the following option: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change seperate the port from the URL by filling the CURL options in an array like so -

```
$ch = curl_init(); 

$options = array(CURLOPT_URL => "http://[ip-address]/connectionscounts?flat/<URI>", 
CURLOPT_PORT => "8086", 
CURLOPT_HEADER => "Content-Type:application/xml", 
CURLOPT_USERPWD => "username:password", 
CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC, 
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE 
); 

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options); 
$data = curl_exec($ch); 

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data); 
print_r($xml);
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel URL is redirect, you can try by adding. This will follow URL to return response.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I still am not getting any results when I add this line.

Comment: try to test by adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC)` as well